# Triangle inequality for integrals of complex functions of real variable

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

If $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ is an integrable function on a real interval, then
$$\left| \int_a^b f \right | \le \int_a^b |f| $$
There's a proof of this in Ahlfors' Complex Analysis book which really cool: you just rotate things so that the integral is real by multiplying by $e^{i\theta}$, then apply the similar result for real-valued functions.

**Qeustion:** Can this also be done by something like applying the discrete triangle equality to Riemann sums for partitions and passing through the limit? If so, is there a good reference for it?

Thank you?

Comment: Can? Yes, sure, for Riemann-integrable $f$. You know that the Riemann sums converge to the integral, and applying the triangle inequality gives you a Riemann sum for $\int \lvert f\rvert$. Reference? I doubt it. The rotation proof is so much nicer (and shorter, and works more generally) that probably everybody uses that.

Comment: Oh sweet -thanks! You could use the rotation proof on integrals of functions from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ as long as they're defined componentwise, because then you can interchange the rotation and the integral.

Comment: @DanielFischer - well, thanks for *your* help, anyway. I'm left befuddled by the two answers posted, though, so I'll mull them over more...

Comment: Don't mull too fast. I'll write one too. But first I _need_ to eat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Riemann-integrable functions have the nice property that for every sequence of partitions $P_n = \{ a = a_0^{(n)} < a_1^{(n)} < \dotsc < a_{r_n}^{(n)} = b\}$ of the interval $[a,b]$ whose mesh $\mu(P_n) = \max \{ a_\rho^{(n)} - a_{\rho-1}^{(n)} : 1 \leqslant \rho \leqslant r_n\}$ tends to zero, and every choice of support points $\xi_\rho^{(n)} \in \left(a_{\rho-1}^{(n)},\, a_\rho^{(n)}\right)$, the sequence of Riemann sums

$$R\left(P_n,(\xi^{(n)}),f\right) := \sum_{\rho = 1}^{r_n} f\left(\xi_\rho^{(n)}\right)\cdot (a_\rho^{(n)} - a_{\rho-1}^{(n)})$$

converges to the integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$. That holds for real-valued, complex-valued, or $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued functions. Also, for properly Riemann-integrable functions (defined, bounded, and Riemann-integrable on a compact interval), the absolute value $\lvert f\rvert$ is Riemann-integrable too.

Thus, fixing any sequence of partitions and associated sequence of support points, applying the triangle inequality to each Riemann sum for our chosen sequence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left\lvert R\left(P_n,(\xi^{(n)}),f \right)\right\rvert
&= \left\lvert \sum_{\rho = 1}^{r_n} f\left(\xi_\rho^{(n)}\right)\cdot (a_\rho^{(n)} - a_{\rho-1}^{(n)})\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \sum_{\rho=1}^{r_n} \left\lvert f(\xi_\rho^{(n)})\right\rvert \left( a_\rho^{(n)} - a_{\rho-1}^{(n)}\right)\\
&= R\left(P_n,(\xi^{(n)}),\lvert f\rvert \right),
\end{align}$$

and taking the limit we obtain

$$\left\lvert \int_a^b f(x)\,dx \right\rvert \leqslant \int_a^b \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert\,dx.$$

We didn't use any particular properties of $\mathbb{C}$ here, so the same argument, replacing the absolute modulus with the norm, yields

$$\left\lVert \int_a^b f(x)\,dx \right\rVert \leqslant \int_a^b \left\lVert f(x)\right\rVert\,dx$$

for any Riemann-integrable function with values in some $\mathbb{R}^n$, endowed with whichever (semi-)norm.

Comment: Cool beans. Thank you *very* much. But yeah, the rotation proof is more cool.

Answer (score 0):

The Riemann sums use the supremum and the infimum of $f$ over subintervals of the partition. But the $\sup f$ and $\inf f$ do not make sense if $f$ is complex valued, since $\mathbb{C}$ is not ordered.

Comment: For the terminology I grew up with, those would be the Darboux sums, a Riemann sum can use the value of $f$ in an arbitrary point of the partition interval.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was thinking in the usual (in the sense of most used in texts) way of defining the Riemann integral. I completely agree with Daniel's comment.

Comment: I thought maybe to avoid that problem ($\mathbb{C}$ not ordered) you could break the integral into real & complex parts, find partition with very small mesh so Darboux sums are really close to integral values. Then do the same for integral of modulus. Get common refinement of partitions. Pick arbitrary points in intervals in partition. Sum contributions and use triangle inequality?