# Absolute Value of Complex Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $[a,b]$ be a closed real interval. Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous complex-valued function. Then $$\bigg|\int_{a}^{b} f(t)dt \ \bigg| \leq \int_{a}^{b} \bigg|f(t)\bigg| dt,$$ where the first integral is a complex integral, and the second integral is a definite real integral.

There's a neat "rotational" proof of this in D'Angelo's *An Introduction to Complex Analysis and Geometry*.

**Question:** Can this fact also be proven using the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality? If so, some help would be nice.

Thank you...

Comment: I'm not sure it would be practical to try and prove this using Cauchy Schwartz, but one way to prove it is using Riemann sums. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538329/triangle-inequality-for-integrals-of-complex-functions-of-real-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first state the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for definite integrals:
*Let $u$ and $v$ be real functions which are continuous on the closed interval $[a,b].$ Then 
$$\left(\int_{a}^{b} u(t)v(t)dt \right) \leq \left(\int_{a}^{b} u(t)dt \right)^2 \cdot \left(\int_{a}^{b} v(t)dt \right)^2$$*
Since $F$ is complex-valued, we can write $F(t) = u(t) + iv(t),$ with $u(t), v(t)$ real-valued. Thus $|F(t)|^2 = u^2+v^2.$ Also 
\begin{align}\left(\int_{a}^{b} F(t)dt \right)^2 = \left(\int_{a}^{b} u(t) + iv(t) dt \right)^2.
\end{align}
Observe that
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{a}^{b} u ~dt \right)^2 &= \left(\int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{u}{(u^2+v^2)^{1/4}}(u^2+v^2)^{1/4}dt \right)^2 \\
&\overset{\mathrm{C-S \ ineq.}}{\leq} \left(\int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{u}{(u^2+v^2)^{1/4}}dt \right)^2\left(\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt[4]{u^2+v^2} ~dt \right)^2 \\ &= \left(\int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{u^2}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}dt \right)\left(\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{u^2+v^2} ~dt \right)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{a}^{b} v ~dt \right)^2 &= \left(\int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{v}{(u^2+v^2)^{1/4}}(u^2+v^2)^{1/4}dt \right)^2 \\
&\overset{\mathrm{C-S \ ineq.}}{\leq} \left(\int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{v}{(u^2+v^2)^{1/4}}dt \right)^2\left(\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt[4]{u^2+v^2} ~dt \right)^2 \\ &= \left(\int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{v^2}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}dt \right)\left(\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{u^2+v^2} ~dt \right).
\end{align*}
So 
\begin{align*}
\bigg|\int_{a}^{b} F(t) ~dt \bigg|^2 &= \bigg|\int_{a}^{b} u(t) + iv(t) ~dt \bigg|^2 \\ &= \bigg|\int_{a}^{b} u(t) ~dt + i\int_{a}^{b}v(t) ~dt \bigg|^2 \\ &= \left(\int_{a}^{b} u ~dt \right)^2 + \left(\int_{a}^{b} v ~dt \right)^2 \\ &\leq \left(\int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{u^2}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}dt \right)\left(\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{u^2+v^2} ~dt \right) \\ &+ \left(\int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{v^2}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}dt \right)\left(\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{u^2+v^2} ~dt \right) \\ &= \left(\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{u^2+v^2} ~dt \right)\left(\int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{u^2+v^2}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}dt \right) \\ &= \left(\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{u^2+v^2} ~dt \right)^2 \\ &= 
\left(\int_{a}^{b} \bigg|F(t)\bigg|\right)^2 dt
\end{align*}
Now, recalling that the modulus is always non-negative we can take the square root of both sides and we arrive at the result.

Comment: What you call the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for definite integrals isn't that. The Cauchy-Bun'akovskij-Schwarz inequality says $$\Biggl(\int_a^b u(x)v(x)\,dx\Biggr)^2 \leqslant \int_a^b u(x)^2\,dx\cdot \int_a^b v(x)^2\,dx.$$ Also, your inequality doesn't always hold [it cannot, since the LHS scales differently than the RHS], for $[a,b] = [0,1]$ and $u(x) = v(x) = \sqrt{x}$ we have $\int_0^1 u(x)v(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 x\,dx = \frac{1}{2}$, and $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}\,dx = \frac{2}{3}$, so the right hand side becomes $\bigl(\frac{2}{3}\bigr)^4 = \frac{16}{81} < \frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: What is wrong with that reasoning (or what’s wrong with the calculation): We integrate along the circle of radius r. $| \int \frac{1}{z} dz| \leq \int |\frac{1}{z}| dz = \int \frac{1}{|re^{2 \pi i t}|}r2 \pi i e^{2 \pi i t} dt = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1}2 \pi i e^{2 \pi i t} dt = 0 $

Comment: The thing is that your left most integral (with the absolute value sign outside the complex integral) is a real number while the second integral gives you a complex number…. These two objects are not comparable to each other

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=f_1+if_2$. Let me define the following vectors:

$$v_1=\left(\int f_1 dx, \int f_2 dx\right)$$

$$v_2(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$$

Because of the usual Cauchy Schwarz Inequality involving vectors:

$$f_1(x)\int f_1 dx +f_2(x) \int f_2 dx=v_1\cdot v_2\leq ||v_1|| \cdot ||v_2||=\sqrt{\left(\int f_1 dx\right)^2+\left(\int f_2 dx\right)^2} \sqrt{f_1^2+f_2^2}$$

Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ yields:

$$ \left(\int f_1 dx\right)^2+\left(\int f_2 dx\right)^2\leq \sqrt{\left(\int f_1 dx\right)^2+\left(\int f_2 dx\right)^2} \int \sqrt{f_1^2+f_2^2}dx$$

If $\left(\int f_1 dx\right)^2+\left(\int f_2 dx\right)^2\not=0$, we may divide both sides to get:

$$ \left|\int f dx\right|=\sqrt{\left(\int f_1 dx\right)^2+\left(\int f_2 dx\right)^2} \leq \int \sqrt{f_1^2+f_2^2}dx=\int|f|dx$$

Clearly, if  $\left(\int f_1 dx\right)^2+\left(\int f_2 dx\right)^2=0$ this is inequality is also satisfied.