# $\bigg|\int_{0}^{\infty}f(s)e^{-ias}ds\bigg| \leq C$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

I would like to know for which conditions on the function $f \in C^{1}([0,\infty]) \cap L^{1}([0,\infty])$ there is a constant $C > 0 $ such that
$$
\bigg|\int_{0}^{\infty}f(s)e^{-ias}ds\bigg| \leq C
$$
with $a \in \mathbb{R}$

I have no idea how to do this problem.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @KamalSaleh I have no idea how to do this problem.

Comment: Okay, so where did you get this problem from? This would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: It's on a list of exercises my teacher gave me.

Comment: Have you heard of the Laplace transform? you could re-write the problem that way.

Comment: This integral is smaller than $\int |f|$ so $f\in L^1$ is a sufficient condition ...

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the triangle inequality for complex integrals you have
$$
\bigg|\int_{0}^{\infty}f(s)e^{-ias}ds\bigg| \leq \int_{0}^{\infty}|f(s)e^{-ias}|ds=\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(s)|ds
$$

So you have to require $\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(s)|ds<\infty$ but this is the definition of $f$ belonging to $L^1$, and you are done.

Comment: It is also valid, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538329/triangle-inequality-for-integrals-of-complex-functions-of-real-variable

Comment: Thank you very much